# How can I use a separate DHCP server and have it go through 2 routers in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, cisco-packet-tracer

I am currently using **Cisco Packet Tracer** to simulate a network.

Currently I've got this setup:
[PT DHCP Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEpaT.png)

For some reason I'm not able to get the DHCP server to return an answer to PC1 even though it successfully gets the request.

Here are my configurations:

**R-1**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
    ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
    ip helper-address 10.0.0.2

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
    ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.252
    ip helper-address 10.0.0.2

ip route 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.2
```

**R-2**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
    ip address 10.0.1.2 255.255.255.252
    ip helper-address 10.0.0.2

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
    ip address 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
    ip helper-address 10.0.0.2

ip route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1
```

Hopefully the below will help to explain the configuration a bit better:

*10.0.0.1*=(G0/0) **R-1** (G0/1)=*10.0.1.1*

*10.0.1.2*=(G0/0) **R-2** (G0/1)=*10.0.2.1*

Comment: What is the default gateway on the DHCP server? How are the dhcp scopes defined on the DHCP server?

Comment: That's actually a good point, probably should've stated that heh, the default gateway is 10.0.2.1, start IP 10.0.2.2 with the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

Comment: Those are the parameters for the scope I presume. And what is the default gateway on the DHCP server itself ? Can the DHCP server PING to R1 and R2? Is routing actually enabled on BOTH routers? Just having 2 interfaces/subnets on a router isn't enough. You still need to enable routing and both routers should preferably use the same routing protocol so they can exchange routes. Otherwise R1 has no idea 10.0.2.0/24 is reachable via R2.